# About the principal square root

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$ be a complex function ($z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$).

I have got the next equivalent expression:

\begin{align*}
f(z)=f(x+iy)=\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{2}}+i\cdot sg(y)\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{2}}
\end{align*}

Where $sg(y)=1$ if $y\geq0$  and $sg(y)=-1$ if $y<0$.

My question is the following:

How can I assure that the equivalent expression that I have got is the principal square root?

Comment: The argument of the square root of the second term is negative !

Comment: I have already solved the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and second quadrant should map to the first, and the third and fourth should map to the fourth.

$$(+,+)\to(+,+)$$

$$(-,+)\to(+,+)$$

$$(+,-)\to(+,-)$$

$$(-,-)\to(+,-)$$

Comment: I think you wanted to say that the third and fourth quadrant should map to the fourth quadrant. And why does this result prove that the expression that I have got is the principal square root?

Comment: @user710092: that's right. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to verify that your function is a square root at all, i.e.
$$
 f(z)^2 = z \text{ for all } z \in\Bbb C.
$$
That is a straight forward calculation, and I'll assume that you already did that.

The [principal square root of a complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number) $z$ is the (unique) number $w$ with $w^2 =z$ which can be written in polar coordinates as
$$
 w = r e^{i \phi} \text{ with } r \ge 0,  -\pi/2 < \phi \le \phi/2 \, .
$$

Therefore you have to verify that $f(z)$ is either a number in the right half-plane, or on the non-negative imaginary axis:

- If $z = x+iy$ with $x \le  0$  and $y= 0$ then 
  $$
  f(z) = 0 + i \sqrt{x}
  $$
- Otherwise $x > 0$ or $y \ne 0$, so that
  $$
   x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} > 0 \implies \operatorname{Re} f(z) > 0 \, .
  $$